# How to read appsettings.json of parent projetc inside a Nuget Package project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating an application that will be a Nuget Package. Let's say the name of this application is MyPackage.

I'll install this package in another project. Let's say this project's name is MyProject.

How can I read in the MyPackage project the appsettings.json of the MyProject project?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple options off the top of my head. Both assume you're participating in Dependency Injection and that by "appsettings.json" you actually mean the configuration framework.

One option is to specify `IConfiguration` as a dependency. This gives you access to all of the configuration keys. Assuming you're using constructor injection, it would look something like this:

```
public class MyPackageClass
{
    public MyPackageClass(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // use configuration here
    }
}
```

A better option is to export a configuration class from your package, bind that class to configuration in your dependency registration code, and inject it into your package classes using `IOptions` or `IOptionsMonitor`.

Let's say your configuration class looks like this:

```
public class MyPackageSettings
{
    public string FirstSetting { get; set; }
}
```

Your registration code would look something like this:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyPackage(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuraiton)
    {
        services.Configure<MyPackageSettings>(configuration.GetSection("MyPackage");

        // add other package classes to services

        return services;
    }
}
```

And you would consume the configuration in your package classes like this:

```
public class MyPackageClass
{
    public MyPackageClass(IOptions<MyPackageSettings> options)
    {
        string firstSettingValue = options.Value.FirstSetting;
    }
}
```

Your documentation would need to specify that users must provide the configuration in their appsettings.json (or other configuration source). For appsettings.json it would need to look something like this:

```
{
    "MyPackage": {
        "FirstSetting": "one"
    }
}
```

More about using options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0